# Couldn't find Agenda without an 'id'=concerts

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I'm trying to do a Agenda of Concerts of the band and have this error in set_agenda method.

```
  ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound at /agendas/concerts
    Couldn't find Agenda with 'id'=concerts

 private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_agenda
      @agenda = Agenda.find(params[:id])
    end
```

I generate a Agenda scaffold before:

```
$ rails g scaffold Agenda title info:text date_concert:date begin_time:time end_time:time
```

Then everything works fine but when I try to add a method called concerts, I have a erro who I don't know what to do. I'm a beginner in Rails and I want a Help.

This is my AgendaController:

```
class AgendasController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_agenda, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :concerts]


  def concerts
      @user= User.find(params[:id])
      @agendas= @user.agendas.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  # GET /agendas
  # GET /agendas.json
  def index
    @agendas = Agenda.all
  end

  # GET /agendas/1
  # GET /agendas/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /agendas/new
  def new
    @agenda = Agenda.new
  end

  # GET /agendas/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /agendas
  # POST /agendas.json
  def create
    @agenda = Agenda.new(agenda_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @agenda.save
        format.html { redirect_to @agenda, notice: 'Agenda was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @agenda }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @agenda.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /agendas/1
  # PATCH/PUT /agendas/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @agenda.update(agenda_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @agenda, notice: 'Agenda was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @agenda }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @agenda.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /agendas/1
  # DELETE /agendas/1.json
  def destroy
    @agenda.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to agendas_url, notice: 'Agenda was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_agenda
      @agenda = Agenda.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def agenda_params
      params.require(:agenda).permit(:title, :info, :date_concert, :begin_time, :end_time)
    end
end
```

My model Agenda.rb

```
class Agenda < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    default_scope -> { order(date_concert: :desc) }
    validates :title, presence: true
    validates :info, presence: true, length: { maximum: 140 }
end
```

My view concerts.html.erb(I want to show the next concerts of the band!)

```
<h1> Agenda Concerts </h1>

<ol>
    <li>
        <%= form_for(@agendas) do |agenda| %>
            <span class="title"><%= link_to agenda.title, agenda_path %></span>
            <span class="info"><%= agenda.info %></span>
            <span class="date"><%= agenda.date_concert %></span>
            <span class="begin_time"><%= agenda.begin_time %></span>
            <span class="end_time"><%= agenda.end_time %></span>
            <span class="timestamp">
                Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(agenda.created_at) %> ago.
            </span>
        <% end %>
    </li>
</ol>
<%= will_paginate @agendas %>
```

My model user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :agendas
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
=begin
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me,
                    :first_name, :last_name, :profile_name, :full_name
=end

    def full_name
        "#{first_name}" + " " + "#{last_name}"
    end
end
```

my routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get 'session/new'
  get 'session/create'

  get 'gallery/lightbox'
  get 'gallery/caroussel'


devise_for :users, :skip => :registrations

resources :agendas do
    member do 
        get :concerts
    end
end




end
```

Comment: Not enough for an answer... If I am correct, the standard URL structure goes `/agendas/:id/concerts`, similar to how edit works (`/agenda/:id/edit`)

Comment: Try changing this `<%= link_to agenda.title, agenda_path %>` to `<%= link_to agenda.title, concerts_agenda_path(agenda) %>`

Comment: This doesn't work. I need to finish this web in this week I use:

Answer (score 0):

When you run `rake routes` you will find this

```
concerts_agenda GET  /agendas/:id/concerts(.:format)   agendas#concerts
```

So try changing

```
<%= link_to agenda.title, agenda_path %>
```

to

```
<%= link_to agenda.title, concerts_agenda_path(agenda) %>
```

If the above doesn't work, then try the below

```
<%= link_to agenda.title, agenda_path(agenda) %>
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I need to finish this web in this week then resuming the code, I use on the view show: <% if user_signed_in? %> .. all table and links (edit, delete).. <% end %> and just shows the entire table and links if the user is logged and if isn't shows the Agenda Concert. I Set up devise as a single user system and works good. Thank's for the help guys!